# How to add version info to Cmdlets pssnapin

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I am creating a cmdlets module by inheriting the CustomPSSnapin class. I have created getter methods for properties like Name, Vendor and Descriptor. Now I want to add version info to this snapin module. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by creating a manifest for your PowerShell module.

Here is a [Microsoft MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878337(v=vs.85).aspx) explaining PowerShell modules manifests.

You will most likely use the [`New-ModuleManifest`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd819477.aspx) cmdlet to generate your manifest. Use the `-ModuleToProcess` switch to specify the `.dll` file you built.